# Run odoo in Virtual Environment

Tags: virtualenv, odoo-11

I've tried to run odoo 11 in Virtual Environment (virtualenv), then I've got this error:

ImportError: No module named 'PyPDF2'

However it works correctly when running service instead of virtual environment.
Can you help me?

Comment: That is odd that the virtual environment could crash, while the service (which SHOULD be based on the VE) runs fine. It could only be a matter not enablind the correct VE ("workon odooX") or installing the requirements (pip3 install -r requirements) on said environment. Check the ExecStart line from your "correct" service file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages those are missing in your current VM machine, so go to odoo11 direcory and run command **pip install -r requirements.txt** (using root user) and then try again.

Comment: @bjr_tlb Which python version you are using. This error comes up when you are using python2, so setup virtualenv for python3.

Comment: It was already setup for python 3. I solve it; I install requirements.txt  using pip3 from my virtualenv. Thanks